# Nestjs: Import a shared module with its configuration into another module

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have a Dynamic Module using Custom Configuration like

Previous Main Module

```
@Module({
  imports: [SharedModule.register({ folder: './config' })],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
  exports: [AppService]
})
export class MainModule {}
```

Shared Module

```
@Module({})
export class SharedModule {
  static register(): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: SharedModule,
      providers: [SharedService],
      exports: [SharedService],
    };
  }
}
```

NewModule

```
@Module({
  imports: [SharedModule.register({ folder: './config' })], // DO NOT WANT TO REPEAT THIS
})
export class NewModule {
  static register(): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: NewModule,
      providers: [NewService],
      exports: [NewService],
    };
  }
}
```

If used in the main module/application works fine.
Now I want to use the same module in another shared module but using the same configuration

MainModule ------------------> SharedModule
|                           ^
|                           |
---------> NewModule--------

How to pass the same configuration to both modules to be independent (NewModule and SharedModule) but in this particular case use the same instance of the services?

Trying out

```
@Module({
  imports: [SharedModule.register({ folder: './config' })],
  imports: [NewModule.register({ folder: './config' })], // THIS IS THE SAME CONFIG 
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
  exports: [AppService]
})
export class MainModule {}
```